# A Critical Point of the Length Functional is a Geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, calculus-of-variations, geodesic

Let $S$ be a surface. Let $\alpha:[0,L] \rightarrow S$ be a curve. A family of curves $\{\alpha_t:[0,L]\rightarrow S\}_{t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)}$ is said to be a variation of $\alpha$ if $\alpha_0=\alpha$, $\alpha(0)=\alpha_t(0)$ and $\alpha(L)=a_t(L)$ for any $t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Moreover, for any fixed $s \in [0,L]$, $\alpha_t(s)$ is a smooth function in $t$. The vector field $V(s)=\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\alpha_t(s)$ is called the variation vector field.

I want to show that $\alpha$ is a geodesic iff for any variation $\{\alpha_t:[0,L]\rightarrow S\}_{t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)}$ of $\alpha$, we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} Length(\alpha_t)=0$$
where $Length$ denotes the arc length of the curve.

For the 'if'  direction, it is the direct consequence of the first variation formula for arc length.

What I cannot understand it is 'only if' direction. By the assumption and the first variation formula, we have
$$\int_{0}^LV(s) \bullet(\alpha''(s))^Tds=\int_{0}^LV(s) \bullet\alpha''(s)ds=0$$
for any variation vector field, where $(\bullet)^T$ denotes the component of the vector on the tangent plane. By my lecture note, it immediately concludes that $(\alpha''(s))^T=0$. I am confused how it can jump that fast to conclusion. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations

Comment: But $V$ cannot be ANY smooth function (since it has to be a variation vector field), so I don't see why it follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus of variation.

Comment: Every smooth, compactly supported vector field is the variation field of some smooth variation - just take $\alpha_t(s) = \exp_{\alpha(s)}(tV(s)).$